# How are Packet header fields ordered in binary stream?

Tags: networking, encapsulation, packet

I have just been refreshing my networking knowledge and came across a question regarding packet (segments, frames .. does not matter really).

There are many diagrams of the packet or segment header on the internet and its quite understandable. How are but these fields ordered in a binary stream flowing through cable and how does translator figure out that one packet has ended and another begins while just receiving ones and zeros?

Thanks

Comment: if the protocol is TCP it will handle the ordering and request the ones didn't arrive. If its UDP, you just lost it.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding this requires understanding [the OSI 7 layer model](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/ddos/glossary/open-systems-interconnection-model-osi/).

If you want to specifically talk about data flowing through a cable, and assuming you mean TCP/ IP data over Ethernet, then Ethernet is a layer 1 & layer 2 protocol. How the data is physically transmitted depends on whether it's full or half duplex, whether it's 8 wire, 4 wire or 2 wire (though 2 wire protocols are propriety like EtherCAT) and other such physical transmission concerns. Typically, a [PHY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHY) chip sits at either end of a cable and passes up Layer 2 data to some kind of [MAC layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control).

Anyway, getting to the point regarding when does a listener know when a packet starts and finishes, the ethernet protocol defines a 7 byte preamble and start of frame delimiter and a 4 byte Frame Check Sequence. You can read more about it [here](http://www.highteck.net/EN/Ethernet/Ethernet.html).

Software to process packets that runs on a CPU will typically never see any of that though. Ethernet frames will pass their *payloads* into a buffer where it will be stored sequentially until it's read or overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Simply to say, one of the Protocol in handling these process is TCP (Layer 4) protocol, which sends the split data with index as 0,1,2,3 and in receiving side obviously it may receive in order 3,1,0,2 or in order 1,2,0,3 or any other but the TCP append data by index

I explain in Layman point

Study about the OSI Reference Model and Networking basics